# Problem in Bluetooth connection over SPP in Android 2.3.3 in Nexus One?

Tags: android, connection, bluetooth

I just updated Nexus One with Android 2.3.3 and it seems that the bluetooth connection over SPP have stopped working in my app.

The same app works alright in HTC Desrire with Android 2.2 and the same app use to work properly on Nexus One too. The problem started after upgrading to Android 2.3.3.

Can anyone let me know what may be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by using createInSecureRfcommSocket API and also there is a way of connecting through reflection for insecure connections.

Answer (score 0):

I found the same issue.  I was not able to get the reflection to work for insecure comms, but the public interface did work.

The symptom is that the connect() call throws the IOException "Connection Refused" every time on 2.3.3, while the code worked fine on 2.2.

I opened a defect against android here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15919&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

Comment: @Dennis Mathews - reflection is a way to "cheat" and access private methods.  E.g. Method m = mDevice.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[]{int.class});    mBluetoothSocket = (BluetoothSocket)m.invoke(mDevice, Integer.valueOf(1));

Comment: Notes from android dev team - this is not a defect, but rather fixing a defect in previous versions that mislead me (and probably others) into thinking a socket was secure when it was not.  See the link already posted for the full explanation.