# Bluetooth SPP error - competition with other BroadcastReceivers?

Tags: android, bluetooth, serial-port, broadcastreceiver

I have an interesting situation where I am communicating, via Bluetooth SPP, with a third party device and intermittent problems arise.

Background on the device:
The device is a barcode scanner acts as a Bluetooth server, using SPP over RFCOMM. It always initiates the connection, and will refuse incoming connections. Upon connection, it will upload data and then wait for an ACK. If the ACK is received, then the same transmission will not be retried. If no ACK is received in the (relatively short) timeout period, then the transmission will be continually retried. The device knows where the data is being sent because it scans a barcode that contains the BDA of the device that will be receiving the transmission. The scanner is never discoverable and never scans for devices.

When a transmission is made and there is no application running, Android on the tablet displays the toast: "Remote device is trying to access your phone. Check in the notifications panel."

What I need and what works up to this point:
Essentially, I need to accept incoming data from the scanner and then reply with an acknowledgment. Since it is a specific app for a specific device, automatic pairing was on my wishlist. (The device always uses "0000" as its PIN).

I have a Samsung Galaxy Tablet for development, although I have also tested with a Nexus One (HTC Passion) and a Samsung Galaxy Vibrant phone.

I started with the Bluetooth chat sample, and have browsed many Stackoverflow questions in my travels. Over time, this is what happened:

1: I started with a basic "createRfcomm...()" using the standard SPP UUID, and then followed up with a "connect()". Although there were some timing issues, I was able to semi-reliably create a connection, obtain read and write streams, receive the data and send the acknowledgement.

The problem was that it was unreliable, and I had to put it in a rather tight loop just to get anything.

2: I discovered the BroadcastReceiver for ACL_CONNECT. I register it during my OnResume(), and things changed considerably. In addition, I registered the the "PAIRING_REQUEST" to handle my automatic pairing, even though it isn't supported directly by the 2.0+ API.

Most notably, I now detect incoming connection attempts and then start the connect(). Interestingly, however, it seems that this may be a little too late - which is really, I suspect, where my main problem arises.

So - the connection attempt comes in and if it is not paired, the PAIRING_REQUEST action is recognized. By using the "createBond", "setPin", and "setPairingConfirmation" functions, all through reflexion, my device is now automatically paired. It works seamlessly on the two mobile phones. However, on the tablet, every now and again the PIN entry dialog will pop up for a split second before it disappears. In any event, the automatic pairing always works.

It is important to note that even while my app is running, the system notification "Remote device is trying to access your phone..." comes up.

After the pairing is complete, whether during a previous transmission or the current one, it moves to the connect(). The first problem is this:

More than 99% of the time, the first connect() attempt times out (approximately 12 seconds). Immediately upon failure, I attempt to connect() again, and most of the time it works. Sometimes, it takes a few more tries, and sometimes it is unsuccessful, but normally it works after a few retries.

Interestingly, whether it succeeds or not, Android will respond with the toast: "Unable to pair with Bluetooth device". This **really** makes no sense to me because the device is paired, and the only thing that is failing is the system (default BroadcastReceiver?) is not making a connection.

At this point my question became - Why does the first connect() always fail? Does it have to do with the notification and the eventual failure? Can I override this? Or, is it something else that I am missing?

The next thing that I tried was setting the priority and aborting the broadcast, but I realized that the Bluetooth broadcast was not ordered. No dice.

What I would really like to know is:

A: Can I instruct Android to ignore this incoming connection attempt, and let my app handle it?

B: Alternatively, can I force the system to abort whatever it is doing (perhaps blocking the channel?) and then let me try my own connect()? At the very minimum, it shouldn't just continuing working until it toasts me with "Unable to pair Bluetooth device" for a device that is already paired.

C: Is there a way just to "Open a COM port" and then deal with connections as they happen? Simply put - can I just get an open port with a raw stream?

D: Is there anything else that anybody thinks that I'm missing?

Additional info:

There are zero problems on the Nexus. It works consistently, every time, with no delay whatsoever. It is running 2.3.3. This is very much in contrast to this:

[Problem in Bluetooth connection over SPP in Android 2.3.3 in Nexus One?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246735/problem-in-bluetooth-connection-over-spp-in-android-2-3-3-in-nexus-one)

The Samsung Vibrant is the worst - most connections fail. It is running 2.2. The tablet is also running 2.2, and as I stated, the majority of connections work after a couple of retires.

Any suggestions on how I might tackle what I think is competition for the broadcast would be very much appreciated. For the sake of completeness, by connect() code follows:

```
    try
{
    // Make sure that there is no discovery going on
    btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

    // Attempt to create the socket
    btSocket = currentBtDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));
    btDebugStage = DEBUG_STAGE_HAS_SOCKET;
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
}

try
{
    // Attempt to connect to the Bluetooth device
    btDebugStage = DEBUG_STAGE_ATTEMPT_CONNECT;
    btSocket.connect();

    btDebugStage = DEBUG_STAGE_CONNECTED;
    btConnected = true;
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    try
    {
        btSocket.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e2)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to close() socket after connection failure", e2);
    }

    // If it doesn't connect then make a note of it
    btConnected = false;
}
```

Comment: I've noticed that Android's implementation of BT just in plain words sucks.  Its buggy and doesn't allow you to manually call up the setPin methods.  It won't pair with older devices without a pin request and sometimes that pin dialog doesn't show up automatically, but yet it shows it pairs in the bonded devices.  Also I've noticed each phone works slightly different with BT especially when using SPP.  I would stay away from android or make sure the BT chips are 3.0 and your device is 3.0 Bluetooth.

Answer (score 1):

Android's Bluetooth may still have some glitches, however, in this case you wrote about the remote BT-Device:

> It always initiates the connection, and will refuse incoming connections.

In your code snippet, you try just what should not work: Initiate a connection *from* the Android device *to* the remote device.

> I now detect incoming connection attempts and then start the connect()

This is almost certainly the completely wrong approach - and, actually, it should **not** work at all. If it does intermittently on some devices this is more of a bug in those devices than an undocumented feature.

So, when dealing with *incoming* Bluetooth connections on Android, use the listening server approach described e.g. in:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html#ConnectingAsAServer

using [listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.UUID%29).

As for the pairing on Android devices: Pairing should be necessary only once for each remote device. Once the device is paired, Android stores the pairing information and will allow future connections without prompting for a PIN for pairing again.